# how to get the full event object when using RadioGroup in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, radio-button, radio-group

hello guys am stuck in a little problem, am using RadioGroup in react and my problem is that i cant get the event object instead i get only the value, in my case i want to get the name and the value when the `onChange` event fire

```
 <RadioGroup name="distance" onChange={handleChange}>
     <Radio value="0.5">0.5</Radio>
     <Radio value="2000">1</Radio>
     <Radio value="3000">2</Radio>
     <Radio value="4000">3</Radio>
     <Radio value="5000">4</Radio>
 </RadioGroup>
```

```
 const handleChange = (e) => {
    console.log(e);//getting only the value
   
  };
```

Comment: Are you using Material-UI for this?

Comment: @turchak no am using chakra ui and i did also try react-radio-group but they work the same way

Comment: from the [doc](https://chakra-ui.com/radio#usage) you should get the whole object and access the value by e.target.value. Maybe you're not using chakra component ?

Comment: Can't reproduce. Here is your code outputting the Synthetic event object: https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-gates-ow8k9?file=/src/index.js - @turchak is on to something :-)

Comment: i did upgrade to chakra-ui-next and i didnt find anything in the docs on how to get the full event  object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is two difference in `next version (v1.x)` and `stable version v0.x` of `chakra-ui`

in `<RadioGroup />` (v0.x)

```
onChange?: (
    event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>,
    value: IRadio["value"],
  ) => void;
```

and in `<RadioGroup />` (v1.x)

```
onChange?(nextValue: StringOrNumber): void;
```

And if you wanna get access to the event, you may downgrade the version of your `chakra-ui`

Comment: i dont want to downgrade so in this moment the way i see it work is only by using html and css to achieve what i wanna do, anyway thanks man i hope they add the acces to the full event object soon

Answer (score 2):

I have not try to repoduce your case, but try something like this:

```
onChange={e => handleChange(e)}
```

than in cb

```
const handleChange = (e, value) => {console.log(e, value)}
```

Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem since I wanted my `handleChange` to work on any type of field, I have set it up like so.

```
const [formData, setFormData] = React.useState({
    inputField: "",
    checkBoxField: false,
    emailField: "",
    distance: "" /* radioField */
})


function handleChange(event) {
    const { name, value, type, checked } = event.target
    setFormData(prevFormData => {
        return {
            ...prevFormData,
            [name]: type === "checkbox" ? checked : value
        }
    })
}
```

As a workaround, I wrote a function that returns a *fake* event.

```
function createEvent(name, value) {
    return {
        target: {
            name: name,
            value: value,
            type: "radio",
            checked: false
        }
    }
}
```

And then my `RadioGroup` would be like this:

```
<RadioGroup
    name="distance"
    onChange={
        function(value) {
            props.handleChange(
                createEvent("distance", value)
            )
        }
    }
>
    <Radio value="0.5">0.5</Radio>
    <Radio value="2000">1</Radio>
    <Radio value="3000">2</Radio>
    <Radio value="4000">3</Radio>
    <Radio value="5000">4</Radio>
</RadioGroup>
```

But yea, putting `name="distance"` as `RadioGroup`'s property won't matter anymore. Works if we only need a few attributes of `event.target`, but still hoping that they'd add access to the full event object soon.